# Couple questions I have regarding my VB Script

Tags: vbscript

I really didn't know what to set the title as. Sorry for being too vague. I have a couple questions specific to my VB Script.

First off, I have a piece that determines how much RAM is installed in my PC. I would like it to output as one amount. Currently, it outputs each slot in my computer. For example...

```
Capacity:, 1024, Speed:, 1333
Capacity:, 1024, Speed:, 1333
Capacity:, 1024, Speed:, 1333
Capacity:, 1024, Speed:, 1333
```

I want it to output as one line, combined (in my case, 4 GB). Here is my code:

```
'Finds the computer's RAM capacity and speed.

strComputer = "."
        Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" _
            & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")

        Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_PhysicalMemory")

        For Each objItem in colItems    
        convertedResult = objItem.Capacity/1048576

            MyFile.WriteLine ("Capacity:, " & convertedResult & ", Speed:, " & objItem.Speed)
Next
```

My next issue is I want to find out what network adapters are in my PC, and their MAC address. I simply want to find the physical LAN adapters and WLAN adapters. I do not want any virtual adapters.

```
'Finds the computer's network adapters' name and MAC address (this includes virtual adapters).

strComputer = "."
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" _
    & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")

Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_NetworkAdapter")

For Each objItem in colItems
    MyFile.WriteLine ("Name:, " & objItem.Name & ", MAC Address:, " & objItem.MACAddress)
Next
```

Comment: -1 for not thinking about the title, and all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the memory, try this:

```
    strComputer = "."
    Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" _
        & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")

    Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_PhysicalMemory")

    dim total

    For Each objItem in colItems    
      convertedResult = objItem.Capacity/1048576
      total = total + convertedResult
    Next


    MyFile.WriteLine ("Capacity:, " & total )
```

Comment: Had to set var total to var = total to get it to work. It did work, but what exactly did you change to make it work?

Comment: I made a mistake...  I am going to edit the code, var (aka variable) is wrong (that's javascript , lol).

Comment: I wasn't trying to be a jerk about it either, lol. But what was the change that got it working?

Comment: all we are doing is declaring a variable named total and incrementally adding the total memory.   Please upvote if my answer helped. =)

Comment: I would love to upvote, but sadly I'm not high enough to do so. I'll mark it as answer whenever I get my network adapter answer (if I don't get it soon, I'll just mark yours as answer).